# In builder pattern, is method `buildpart()` a factory method?

Tags: design-patterns, builder, factory-method

In builder design pattern,

[image]

is method `buildpart()` a factory method? (For comparison, an abstract factory is a collection of factory methods.)

Why are they (not) factory methods? For clarification, could you also provide the definition of a factory method?

An example for `buildpart()` from Design Patterns by Gamma et al is:

```
void StandardMazeBuilder::BuildMaze  () {
_currentMaze  = new Maze;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A factory method creates a concrete object/product, usually with the `new` keyword, and *returns* that object. Typicall the name of a factory method starts with prefix `create`.

The `buildpart()` method in the context of Builder Pattern may create some object, but *does not return* that object. From the perspective of the Director, it does not need to receive the part created by the `buildpart()` method. The Director just wants to instruct the Builder to build parts in a wanted order, and finally receive the final product.

In short, due to the difference between `create` and `build`, a `buildpart()` method is not a factory method.