# Is `Clone()` in prototype pattern considered as a factory method?

Tags: design-patterns

Design Patterns by Gamma et al describes Prototype pattern:

[image]

Is `Clone()` considered as a factory method?   (For comparison, an abstract factory is a collection of factory methods.)

Why are they (not) factory methods? For clarification, could you also provide the definition of a factory method?

An example of `Clone()` is

```
Door* Door::Clone  () const {
return new Door(*this);
}
```

There is a similar question [In builder pattern, is method `buildpart()` factory methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509460/in-builder-pattern-is-method-buildpart-factory-methods)

Comment: No: the Factory Method Pattern requires class inheritance; the Prototype pattern avoids class inheritance.